# ValueError: Unknown loss function: categorical crossentropy. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, chatbot, valueerror

I am trying to build a chatbot for a University project, by following a youtube tutorial and basically having zero experience. Everything worked fine until now, and I get a ValueError.

This is what I receive when I run the code:

```
C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\python.exe C:\Users\Kimbe\PycharmProjects\chatbot\training.py 
C:\Users\Kimbe\PycharmProjects\chatbot\training.py:53: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  training = np.array(training)
2022-11-23 21:38:00.366897: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2022-11-23 21:38:00.367881: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:263] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2022-11-23 21:38:00.371587: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: Kims-Surface
2022-11-23 21:38:00.371782: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: Kims-Surface
2022-11-23 21:38:00.372191: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers\optimizer_v2\gradient_descent.py:111: UserWarning: The `lr` argument is deprecated, use `learning_rate` instead.
  super().__init__(name, **kwargs)
Epoch 1/200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kimbe\PycharmProjects\chatbot\training.py", line 69, in <module>
    model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
  File "C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\Kimbe\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filecynafcyn.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 994, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1052, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 240, in __call__
        self.build(y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 182, in build
        self._losses = tf.nest.map_structure(
    File "C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 353, in _get_loss_object
        loss = losses_mod.get(loss)
    File "C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 2649, in get
        return deserialize(identifier)
    File "C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 2603, in deserialize
        return deserialize_keras_object(
    File "C:\Users\Kimbe\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 769, in deserialize_keras_object
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Unknown loss function: categorical crossentropy. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my code:

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np

import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['?', '!', '.', ',']

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(word_list)
        documents.append((word_list, intent['tag']))
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
words = sorted(set(words))

classes = sorted(set(classes))

pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(words, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))

training = []
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)

for document in documents:
    bag = []
    word_patterns = document[0]
    word_patterns = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_patterns]
    for word in words:
        bag.append(1) if word in word_patterns else bag.append(0)

    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])

    random.shuffle(training)
    training = np.array(training)


    train_x = list(training[:, 0])
    train_y = list(training[:, 1])

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))

    sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='categorical crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
    model.save('Chatbot_model.model')

    print("Done")
```

I googled a bit and tried out different fixes but none of them seemed to work.
Since it says something about rebuilding tensorflow I assume I need to redownload it and do the code again?
Before, the tensorflow and the code seemed to be running fine but after adding random.shuffle this error came.

Would be nice if anybody could help me out. Thank you! :)

Comment: There is no space in the actual name of the loss, there should be an underscore: categorical_crossentropy

Answer (score -1):

you may need to consider the input format as float or int.

Sample: Calculation is beneficial when the sequence is in format, passthrough possible but no meaning when it cannot have a load of functions.

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

import tensorflow as tf

import json

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
vocab = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",
",", "ù", "é", "ç", "ô", "À", "à" ]

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
intents = json.loads(open("F:\\temp\\Python\\chatbots\\intents.json").read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['?', '!', '.', ',']

list_classes = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
list_words = [ ]
list_label = [ ]

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(word_list)
        documents.append((word_list, intent['tag']))
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])
            
words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
words = sorted(set(words))

classes = sorted(set(classes))
print( "======================================================================================" )
layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def auto_paddings( data, max_sequences=40 ):
    data = tf.constant( data, shape=(data.shape[0], 1) )
    paddings = tf.constant([[1, 40 - data.shape[0] - 1], [0, 0]])
    padd_data = tf.pad( data, paddings, "CONSTANT" )
    padd_data = tf.constant( padd_data, shape=(40, 1) ).numpy()
    return padd_data

print( "======================================================================================" )

for words_string in words:
    padd_data = auto_paddings( layer( tf.strings.bytes_split(words_string) ), 40 )
    list_words.append( padd_data )
    list_label.append( list_classes[0] )    # requires mapping or supervise learning

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(list_words, shape=(168, 1, 40, 1),dtype=tf.float32), tf.constant(list_label, shape=(168, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 40, 1 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(11),
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=50 )
```

Output: Function revokes with sample inputs, feedback value make sense loss optimizer fn and matrixes value seem to reflect the real truth.

```
Epoch 1/50
2022-11-24 08:13:14.910457: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8100
168/168 [==============================] - 11s 26ms/step - loss: 0.9852 - accuracy: 0.5893
Epoch 2/50
168/168 [==============================] - 5s 27ms/step - loss: 0.2256 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 3/50
104/168 [=================>............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.0082 - accuracy: 1.0000
```